# Setting up a Basic VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, nas

Ok so we are a small company, and I am a Partner cum Computer Enthusiast(and hence IT Administrator) at this company. We have two offices, separated 100km. I have purchased a NAS to be installed in one office. The Local Network setup was a breeze.

However the web-access provided by the manufacturer(seagate) doesn't seem upto the mark. I would like to create a VPN at office 1(where the NAS is located) to which office 2 people can connect and access the NAS as a shared drive. The VPN can essentially consist of just 1 machine(the NAS) to which the office 2 has to connect.

What would be the ways of doing this and steps?(knowing i am not a networks and formally trained computers guy)

Comment: The answer highly depends on the hardware you have available/are willing to aquire. More information on the NAS and how you are hooked up to the Internet would be helpful. For example, some Routers can be set to run a VPN Server and or Client.

Comment: Right now i have only the NAS and 2 basic routers. I do not think they are VPN enabled. I would be willing to purchase hardware below 200$.

Comment: What make/model routers are they? If they have any VPN capability (many do) then this might be easy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to recommend [OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net) as the most suitable solution to your case.
As you have only two clients to connect to the server you can obtain the OpenVPN AS and use the under the free licence quota for two clients. OpenVPN is  cross platform and easily configurable and has a web UI as well

Comment: Does using OpenVPN circemvent the VPN router thing? Is the OpenVPN installed ON THE NAS Machine itself? Also would i require STATIC IP addresses for doing this? I don't think ISPs provide static IPs for broadband connections her in India.

Comment: OpenVPN is not installed by default. and the clients do not require static IPs. have to tried to connect to the NAS server through FTP as mentioned in the seagate site ?

Answer (score 0):

there is many solution for vpn

But i alway use Applience (software or packge ) for handle manage Vpn user and connection

1- kerio

Kerio Control (previously called Kerio WinRoute Firewall and before that WinRoute Pro) is a software gateway firewall developed by Kerio Technologies (earlier known as Tiny Software). Equipped with a VPN server, integrated Sophos anti-virus (optional), web filtering, bandwidth limiter, Internet monitor and user-specific Internet access management, the Kerio Control installs on Windows and Linux, providing network perimeter defense for small to medium organizations.
I use kerio for Many company and suggest to you ... kerio control is a applience virtual or better say is a packet software on debian ( it's a iso for automatic install)
with web gui can mange use and many work higher then just vpn
for vpn connection you have kerio-vpn-client on debian , ubuntu and windows

http://kerio.com/control

2- openvpn

OpenVPN is an open source software application that implements virtual private network (VPN) techniques for creating secure point-to-point or site-to-site connections in routed or bridged configurations and remote access facilities. It uses a custom security protocol[2] that utilizes SSL/TLS for key exchange. It is capable of traversing network address translators (NATs) and firewalls. It was written by James Yonan and is published under the GNU General Public License (GPL)

https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source.html

3- install vpn server on you server and use connection seem pptp or l2tp

But you dont have a good gui for mange user